# Enums in java error

Tags: java, enums

```
enum key{
   ABCD,XYZ
}

public class example {
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
       String Pass,a;
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("enter the password");
       Pass=in.nextLine();
         if(Pass==key.ABCD)
            {
             System.out.println("your password was correct"+key.ABCD);
            }
         else
             {
             System.out.println("your password was incorrect");
             }
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the Java error? Why are you having an enum for password?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - incomparable types: java.lang.String and key
        at example.main(example.java:17)
Java Result:

Comment: You have to convert the string `Pass` to an enum of type `key` to compare them.

Comment: pls modify my code pls

Comment: The exception which you said above is due to your IDE I guess

Comment: Another thing do you have a good reason capitalizing the first character of string `Pass`. You know is a good practice to follow the `Java Code Guidelines/Conventions` in which case you would have named that variable just `pass`. But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `if(Pass==key.ABCD)` with `if(key.valueOf(Pass)==key.ABCD)`.

Or,

Since you have arbitory inputs values to check, it's better to convert the enum value to String and compare it. So change the if condition to `if(Pass.equals(key.ABCD.name()))`

Comment: it giving a msg Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class key.sstfd
        at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:192)
        at key.valueOf(example.java:4)
        at example.main(example.java:17)
Java Result: 1

Comment: your correct Abimaran Kugathasan what is my error ?

Comment: what is meaning of if(Pass.equals(key.ABCD.names()))

Comment: @NaveenMicksen, You have arbitrary inputs, so, converting Enum to String and comparing will work painlessly.

Answer (score 4):

The string `Pass` should be converted to an enum of type `key` first, so change the `if` part to :

```
if(key.valueOf(Pass) == key.ABCD){
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enum key {
    ABCD, XYZ;

    public static key getKeyFromString(String keyStr) {
        key rtnKey = null;
        if (keyStr != null) {
            for (key value : values()) {
                if (keyStr.equalsIgnoreCase(value.toString())) {
                    rtnKey = value;
                    break;

                }
            }
        }
        return rtnKey;

    }
}
```

..................................In main method.................

```
key userKey = key.getKeyFromString(Pass)
```

user usrKey for comparison